# cva.glmnet() lambda value does not give correct number of non-zero predictors in glmnet()

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

I have an issue with specifying the lambda value based on `cva.glmnet()`.

[image]

The lowest "binomial deviance" was attained in my data with `alpha = 1` and `lambda = 0.04126`. It said that there were 43 predictors that were non-zero.

[image]

After this, I used `glmnet()` to create a list of the non-zero predictors, but I only got 27 of them.

[image]

I have the predictors set as factors with 3 levels. I made sure that they were input as factors in `cva.glmnet()` using `do.call()`, and I used that same data through `do.call()` in `glmnet()`.

Does anyone know why using this value of lambda is not getting me the "correct" number of predictors? Is the data not being passed as a `data.frame` in either of the functions? Are some factor levels being counted as multiple predictors?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: One extra note: The predictors have 3 levels, but they are not set up as dummy variables. I'm not sure if that matters here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

`cva.glmnet()` does create dummy variables automatically, it seems. However, `glmnet()` does not.

So, I needed to use the `acm.disjonctif()` function from the `ade4` package to create dummy variables for my predictors to put into the `glmnet()` function. This gave me 43 non-zero predictors, matching `cva.glmnet()`.